# Integral over 2-dim set can defining inequalities added?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

I want to evaluate the following integral over the domain $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}|0\leq x+y\leq 1, 0\leq 2x-3y \leq 4\}$:
$$\int_A \sqrt{x+y}\:\mathrm{d}\lambda(x,y)$$
With the function $\Phi:A \rightarrow\Phi(A),\:(x,y)\mapsto(x+y,2x-3y)$ and the change of variables formula I get:
$$\int_A \sqrt{x+y}\:\mathrm{d}\lambda(x,y)=\frac{8}{15}$$
But if I write $A$ as $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}|y\in[-x,1-x],x\in[0,\frac{7}{5}]\}$ I get:
$$\int_A \sqrt{x+y}\:\mathrm{d}\lambda(x,y)=\frac{14}{15}$$
I think the first one is correct and the sets are not equal but that means its forbidden to add the inequalities that are defining a set. Or where else is the error?

Comment: What do you mean with "its forbidden to add the inequalities that are defining a set."

Comment: If I scale the first inequalities 0≤+≤1 with 3 and add them to 0≤2−3≤4 I get 0≤5≤7 and 0≤+≤1 as my new inequalities, but I‘m not sure if this is allowed. @RafaBudría

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you can add these inequalities (it is granted by the order axioms), but the problem here is the implication. $0\leq x+y\leq 1$ and $0\leq 2x-3y\leq 4$ imply $0\leq 5x\leq 7$ and $0\leq x+y\leq 1$, but the converse is not true.

You cannot infer from $0\leq 5x\leq 7$ and $0\leq x+y\leq 1$ the original inequalities. Because you cannot subtract inequalities.

E.g. set $a=3$, $b=-1$, $a\leq 3$ and $b\leq 1$. But $a-b\leq 3-1=2$ is false.

So, the last definition of set $A$ is not the same as the first one.

This is a definition usable for the integral, although the integral has to be separated in three parts to be added.

$A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}|y\in[-x,\dfrac{2}{3}x],x\in[0,\dfrac{3}{5});\}\cup\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}|y\in[-x,1-x],x\in[\dfrac{3}{5},\dfrac{4}{5});\}\cup$
$\cup\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}|y\in[\dfrac{2}{3}x-4,1-x],x\in[\dfrac{4}{5},\dfrac{7}{5}]\}$